# Lock screen till user completes a particular action

Tags: time-management

At my company, we need to submit a timesheet on a monthly basis. But many employees fail to do this creating a hue and cry at the last moment and needless to say, unwanted escalations!

So I was thinking to come up with some sort of a solution to force employees to submit the timesheet on a weekly basis. Now the timesheets are filled in through a web site designed for this.

so basically at a scheduled time of a day of the week, the system would need to automatially open the timesheet web app through the browser and go full screen. The system would then be required to disallow the user to perform any action till the message "timesheet succesfully submitted" comes up on the web page.

Some validations would be required to ensure that the time is filled up for the entire week.

I was thinking of developing a solution through UiPath to achieve this. But any thoughts on this is welcome!

Comment: Are you looking for already made software to handle this or language recommendations? What is the timesheet software and operating system?

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify in your question if you are looking for a pre-built software solution, of if you are only looking to develop your own solution.  The former is on-topic here, while the latter is not.  Thanks!